# how to get images from an xml file stored as an url in android

Tags: java, android, url, gridview

in my app i am trying to show some images in a grid view manner. normally i know to show grid view for the images stored in drawables.

When the activity opens it hits an url and gets back an xml file. The images are  stored in this xml file as follows.

```
<Search>
  <Searchdata>
     <id>http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/avatars/original/1304429263_spot.jpg</id
  </Searchdata>
  <Searchdata>
     <id>http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/avatars/original/1304429219_spot.jpg</id
  </Searchdata>
  <Searchdata>
     <id>http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/avatars/original/1304429208_spot.jpg</id
  </Searchdata>
</Search>
```

like this it goes on...

I am storing this xml file in a constant value and by sax parser i am getting the values in the tag `<id></id>`

Now how to move all the id tags to my grid views ImageAdapter class file.

Please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reefer below link

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Source is available here http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip

Answer (score 0):

First you want to download these images to obtain Bitmaps that you can pass to your adapter. Check this post: [Multithreading for Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)